# Redirect user in django after form submission using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django, forms, redirect

Using JS to add some interactivity to the form and now would like to redirect the user to a different url and be able to do it dynamically. Using plain JS as of now, need ideas. Adding sample code below.

```
book.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const submitButton = document.getElementById('book');
    submitButton.disabled = true;
    submitButton.innerHTML = 'Booking...';
    setTimeout(() => {
        submitButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fa-solid fa-check" style="color: white; text-align: center;"></i>`;
    }, 1000);
    // return user to profile page
});
```

Not really sure what to try as I am new to using JavaScript.

Comment: Remove `e.preventDefault();`.

Comment: It is important that I don't do that, have been able to fix the issue by using:

document.forms.form.submit();